# Why angular post does not send jsessionid to redirect_uri

Tags: angularjs, spring, authentication, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I've downloaded the JWT version of the oauth2 server (https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2) and I've been trying to replace the default login form to another using angularjs.

That I made was:

1. Create a request mapping for the new login form

`

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login"})
public String redirect(@RequestParam(required = false) String code, @RequestParam(required = false) String state) {
    return "redirect:/#/login";
}
```

`

2. Call to the login endpoint using $http.post (XSRF-TOKEN has been injected with an interceptor):

`

```
var params = {username: credentials.username, password: credentials.password};
var config = {
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'}
};
CoreService.httpPost('login', $httpParamSerializer(params), config)
.then( function(data) {...});
```

`

3. All looks ok, Angular send the information, the client info is obtained from our BD, the user is searched in our Data Base or LDAP. When the user is founded and the login process finish ok, the symtem redirect to the zuul server, but the jsessionid it's not present, so the Zuul server can't validate the token.

However, If I refresh the IU page, the token validation works perfectly

So, could you tell me what I have to do or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I might have a similar one

Comment: No, Sorry but I had to use the default functionality